# PHP Yii2 MYSQL query giving wrong output

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm executing a PHP yii2 query to get records from the database but it's not working. But I directly executed the query in the MYSQL console then it gives me the expected output.

Normal SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_inbox` WHERE sender_id=778 AND recipient_id=736 OR sender_id=778 AND recipient_id=736 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Above query giving me expected result but when i change to Yii2 like :

```
$message=Inbox::find()->select(['message'])->where(['sender_id'=>$sender_id,'recipient_id'=>$recipient_id])->orWhere(['sender_id'=>$recipient_id,'recipient_id'=>$sender_id])->andWhere(['ad_id'=>$ad_id,'category'=>$category])->orderBy(['timestamp'=>SORT_DESC])->one();
```

It gives me the wrong result.

What is my logic :

I have a chat on my website and I need to get the last message order by timestamp. But sender_id and the recipient will be visa versa.

How to fix ?

Comment: Can you show what is the expected result and the wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

There are significant differences between the normal SQL version of the query and the Yii version.

### 1) Selected fields

The normal SQL query selects all fields, but Yii version selects only `message` field.
This is because the normal SQL has `SELECT * FROM ...` but in Yii query you are calling `select(['message'])`. If you want to select all fields you can leave the `select()` method call out or you can use `select('*')`.

### 2) Your conditions are different

Considering operator priority your conditions in normal SQL are:

```
(sender_id=778 AND recipient_id=736) 
  OR (sender_id=778 AND recipient_id=736)
```

But in your Yii version of query:

```
(
  (sender_id=778 AND recipient_id=736)
  OR (sender_id=736 AND recipient_id=778)
) AND (
  ad_id=$ad_id AND category=$category
)
```

In your normal SQL the both sides of OR condition are same but in your Yii version the values for sender/recipient are swapped in the second argument of OR operator.
Also there is extra part added by this call `andWhere(['ad_id'=>$ad_id,'category'=>$category])`

Answer (score 0):

```
$message=Inbox::find()->select(['message'])->where(['sender_id'=>$sender_id,'recipient_id'=>$recipient_id])->orWhere(['sender_id'=>$recipient_id])->orWhere(['recipient_id'=>$sender_id])->andWhere(['ad_id'=>$ad_id,'category'=>$category])->orderBy(['timestamp'=>SORT_DESC])->one();
```

try this

I'm getting following sql

```
SELECT `message` FROM `user` WHERE ((((`sender_id`='2333') AND (`recipient_id`='23222')) OR (`sender_id`='23222')) OR (`recipient_id`='23333')) AND ((`ad_id`='10') AND (`category`='1')) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check raw sql easily, then it will be mostly straight forward how Yii Query builder works.

use following code:

```
$rawSql = Inbox::find()
...
->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

I would change your code into this:

```
$message=Inbox::find()
    ->select(['message'])
    ->where([
        'and',
        [
            'or',
            ['sender_id'=>$sender_id,'recipient_id'=>$recipient_id],
            ['sender_id'=>$recipient_id,'recipient_id'=>$sender_id]
        ],
        ['ad_id'=>$ad_id,'category'=>$category]
    ])
    ->orderBy(['timestamp'=>SORT_DESC])->one();
```